# Error trying to ban ip addresses from apache with fail2ban: Sorry but the jail 'apache' does not exist

Tags: apache-2.4, fail2ban

I want to use fail2ban to block specific ip addresses with:

`sudo fail2ban-client set apache banip 111.111.111.111`

I get:

```
 NOK: ('apache',)
Sorry but the jail 'apache' does not exist
```

I'm also confused because the `jail.conf` file does not contain an entry for `[apache]`. I tried adding it manually and restarting fail2ban. That didn't help.

All the tutorials I've found talk about the `[apache]` jail but it's absent on my stock version of `jail.conf`.

I'm running Debian 10 (buster).

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a single `[apache]` jail, but it might be split to multiple jails for different purposes. As the `[apache]` jail is typically handling the authentication failures, you could be looking for `[apache-auth]`.

Additionally, there might be `[apache-noscript]` to detect clients trying to find exploitable scripts, `[apache-overflows]` for suspiciously long requests, and `[apache-badbots]` for known user-agents of spammer robots etc. The name for `[apache-fakegooglebot]` is self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've seen those jails in the config file. So it doesn't really matter which jail I add the ip address ban to?

Comment: All `[apache-*]` jails on Debian 10 have `port = http,https` by default. Therefore, manually adding an IP address to any of these jails will block its access to ports `80` and `443`.